# PHPMailer and Google SMTP-Relay. Excess duplicate email with receiver receiving other customer email

Tags: smtp, phpmailer

I have created a script that email some tracking details to each customer order that had been shipped off.

The script is built with PHPMailer and sends the emails via Google SMTP-Relay Service.

During testing, all worked as expected. Load tested with 100 emails, albeit to the same email address, all performed as expected. No duplicates or missing emails.

However not long after going live, I been told several customers have received tens of emails with other customers tracking details.

With gmail users, they received the other customer's tracking email with their email address as sent-to.

With outlook users, they receive other customer's email with many emails in the sent-to area.

I have reviewed the code, tested and checked the output of each function, completely lost at where it could have gone wrong.

Below is a sudo process of the script. Looking to see if some one could provide some tips on how I can go about troubleshooting this issue.

1. Retrieve list of emails into 1-D array.
2. Create a PHPMailer instance
3. For each email in array, send email, wait for TRUE response, if FALSE, WAIT 5s, retry total 3 times, if exceed CONTINUE.
4. Once done, script ends.

Other notes

The script is triggered by a windows task scheduler.

The script will take about 2-10mins to run depending on how many retries, though the scheduler is set to run every 5 mins but the task in the scheduler have been set not to run multiple instances of the task if existing is running.

Any suggestions would be great.

Cheers

Snippet of the code. Hopefully will provide sufficient idea.

The general process is the script calls sendTrackingEmails() from Dispatcher_cl.php, where it then uses varies functions from MyCustomerMailer.php. MyCustomerMailer.php is more or less an abstract layer for PHPMailer.

Dispatcher_cl.php

```
public function sendTrackingEmails() {
    try{
        $this->processLog[] = __FUNCTION__;

        /*
        1.Get list of emails
        2.Loop and send emails
        */

        $ordersSent         = array();
        $ordersFailed       = array();
        $result             = false;
        $emailListAndInfo   = $this->getEmailListAndInfo();

        if($emailListAndInfo===false){
            //No orders to dispatch emails. So do nothing.
            $result = false;
        }else{
            $mail = new MyCustomMailer_cl();

            if($mail->setSMTPParam('default')===true){

                foreach($emailListAndInfo as $customer){

                    $sentFrom       = array();
                    $replyTo        = array();
                    $emailTo        = array($customer['email'],$customer['name']);
                    $subject        = array();
                    $body           = null;

                    /*
                        Preset email settings for each brand.
                        When adding vendors, remember to add a BODY template and VENDOR ID to the SQL in [m_getEmailListAndInfo]
                    */
                    if($customer['vendor_id']==3){  
                        //Diamondphoto
                        $sentFrom       = array('no-reply@email.com','Your order has been shipped');
                        $replyTo        = array('no-reply@email.com','Your order has been shipped');
                        $subject        = "Tracking for order {$customer['vendorOrderId']}";
                        $body           = $this->getEmailTemplateFor(3,$customer);


                    }else{
                        /*
                            If vendor_id does not match existing setup, set TRYCOUNT to 99 as indicator and skip remaining execution. 
                            Next script-run will not pick up this record due to 99 will be greater than the usual preset TRYCOUNT.
                        */
                        $this->setTryCountForOrder($customer['order_id'],99);
                        continue;
                    }

                    $emailPackage['sentFrom']   = $sentFrom;
                    $emailPackage['replyTo']    = $replyTo;
                    $emailPackage['emailTo']    = $emailTo;
                    $emailPackage['subject']    = $subject;
                    $emailPackage['body']       = $body;
                    $mail->setupEmail($emailPackage);

                    for($i=1;$i<=$this->emailTryCount;$i++){
                        // $emailSentResult = $mail->send();
                        $emailSentResult = false;

                        if($emailSentResult===true){
                            $setFlagResult = $this->setSentFlagForOrder($customer['order_id'],$i);

                            if($setFlagResult===true){
                                $ordersSent[] = $customer['order_id'];

                                break;
                            }else{
                                throw new Exception("Update sent-flag for order {$customer['order_id']} failed.");
                            }
                        }else if($emailSentResult===false AND $i<$this->emailTryCount){

                            $this->setTryCountForOrder($customer['order_id'],$i);
                            // sleep($this->emailWaitTimer);
                            continue;

                        }else if($emailSentResult===false AND $i==$this->emailTryCount){

                            $this->setTryCountForOrder($customer['order_id'],$i);
                            $ordersFailed[] = $customer['order_id'];

                        }
                    }//End sending/attempting to send tracking email.

                }//End of looping through the emailing list.


            }//End of validation SMTP parameters.

            $result = array('sent'  =>$ordersSent
                            ,'failed'=>$ordersFailed);

        }//End of section for EMAIL-LIST exist



        return $result;

    }catch(Exception $e){
        $this->processLog[] = __FUNCTION__.$e->getMessage();
        throw $e;
    }
}
```

MyCustomerMailer.php

```
    <?PHP

require 'class/PHPMailer5.2/PHPMailerAutoload.php';

class MyCustomMailer_cl{

public $processLog      = array();
private $dbConnect      = null;

private $phpMailer      = null;
private $SMTPDebug      = null;
private $Debugoutput    = null;
private $Host           = null; //smtp.gmail.com OR smtp-relay.gmail.com
private $Port           = null; //587
private $SMTPSecure     = null; //tls or ssl
private $SMTPAuth       = null; //true or false
private $Username       = null;
private $Password       = null;


private $sentFrom       = array();  //array('example@gmail.com','Joe Doe');
private $replyTo        = array();  //array('example@gmail.com','Joe Doe');
private $emailTo        = array();  //array('example@gmail.com','Joe Doe');
private $subject        = null;     //Plain text
private $body           = null;     //Plain text


public function __construct() {
    try{
        $this->processLog[] = __FUNCTION__;


    }catch(Exception $e){
        $this->processLog[] = __FUNCTION__.$e->getMessage();
        throw $e;
    }
}


/*******************************************************************
                    SET functions
********************************************************************/   

public function setSMTPParam($param) {
    /*
        $param can be a text string 'default' or an array.

        $param = array( 'SMTPDebug'     =>null
                        ,'Debugoutput'  =>null 
                        ,'Host'         =>null 
                        ,'Port'         =>null 
                        ,'SMTPSecure'   =>null 
                        ,'SMTPAuth'     =>null 
                        ,'Username'     =>null 
                        ,'Password'     =>null                          
                        );
    */

    try{
        $this->processLog[] = __FUNCTION__;

        $paramError = 0;
        $result = false;


        if($param=='default'){
            $param = array( 'SMTPDebug'         =>0
                            ,'Debugoutput'      =>'html'
                            ,'Host'             =>'smtp-relay.gmail.com'    //smtp.gmail.com OR smtp-relay.gmail.com
                            ,'Port'             =>587
                            ,'SMTPSecure'       =>'tls'
                            ,'SMTPAuth'         =>true
                            ,'Username'         =>"myEmail@email.com"
                            ,'Password'         =>"myPassword"                          
                        );

        }else if(!is_array($param)){
            throw new Exception('ERROR1901155: SMTP parameter is not an array.');
        }

        //Validation - 2019.01.17 need more work, script randomly fails check here.
        foreach($param as $parameter){
            if($parameter===''  OR is_null($param)){
                $paramError++;
            }
        }


        if($paramError==0){
            $this->SMTPDebug        = $param['SMTPDebug'];
            $this->Debugoutput      = $param['Debugoutput'];
            $this->Host             = $param['Host'];
            $this->Port             = $param['Port'];
            $this->SMTPSecure       = $param['SMTPSecure'];
            $this->SMTPAuth         = $param['SMTPAuth'];
            $this->Username         = $param['Username'];
            $this->Password         = $param['Password'];

            $this->phpMailer = new PHPMailer;
            $this->phpMailer->isSMTP();

            $this->phpMailer->SMTPDebug     = $this->SMTPDebug;
            $this->phpMailer->Debugoutput   = $this->Debugoutput;
            $this->phpMailer->Host          = $this->Host;
            $this->phpMailer->Port          = $this->Port;
            $this->phpMailer->SMTPSecure    = $this->SMTPSecure;
            $this->phpMailer->SMTPAuth      = $this->SMTPAuth;
            $this->phpMailer->Username      = $this->Username;
            $this->phpMailer->Password      = $this->Password;

            $result = true;
        }

        return $result;

    }catch(Exception $e){
        $this->processLog[] = __FUNCTION__.$e->getMessage();
        throw $e;
    }
}   



public function setupEmail($data) {
    try{
        $this->processLog[] = __FUNCTION__;



        $this->sentFrom     = $data['sentFrom'];
        $this->phpMailer->setFrom($this->sentFrom[0],$this->sentFrom[1]);

        $this->replyTo      = $data['replyTo'];
        $this->phpMailer->addReplyTo($this->replyTo[0],$this->replyTo[1]);

        $this->emailTo      = $data['emailTo'];
        $this->phpMailer->addAddress($this->emailTo[0],$this->emailTo[1]);

        $this->subject      = $data['subject'];
        $this->phpMailer->Subject = $this->subject;

        $this->body         = $data['body'];
        $this->phpMailer->msgHTML($this->body);

    }catch(Exception $e){
        $this->processLog[] = __FUNCTION__.$e->getMessage();
        throw $e;
    }
}   

public function send() {
    try{
        $this->processLog[] = __FUNCTION__;
        $result = false;
        if (!$this->phpMailer->send()) {
            // throw new exception("error20190114: Failed to send at final stage.");
            $result = false;
        }else{
            $result = true;
        }

        return $result;


    }catch(Exception $e){
        $this->processLog[] = __FUNCTION__.$e->getMessage();
        throw $e;
    }
}   

public function sendWithRetry($attempt=3,$waitTime=5) {
    try{
        $this->processLog[] = __FUNCTION__;
        $result = false;

        for($i=1;$i<=$attempt;$i++){

            if(!$this->phpMailer->send()){
                if($i==$attempt){
                    break;
                }else{
                    continue;
                }

            }else{
                $result=true;
                break;
            }
        }

        return $result;

    }catch(Exception $e){
        $this->processLog[] = __FUNCTION__.$e->getMessage();
        throw $e;
    }
}
```

}

?>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I’m not sure how you expect anyone to be able to debug your code if you don’t show it, but I would guess you’re not aware of what `addAddress` does (it’s not called `setAddress` for a reason), and you’re probably not calling  `clearAddresses` within your sending loop.

Your send speed is also very poor; I would expect sending 100 messages to take no longer than a few seconds.

Take a look at the mailing list example provided with PHPMailer which addresses all of these things. Performance advice can also be found on the PHPMailer project wiki.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your feedback. Originally I didnt think any would want the code to do actual debugging. But I have added to it for any other that may want to review it.

I'm super surprised you said the speed is very poor, as the posts that I've seen suggest its normal. Personally I would agree with you. It means I have missed something critical.

And yes, I will review the addAddress and the clearAddresses. I must have missed something important when going through the samples. Thank you!

Comment: Stack overflow is **all** about the code! While that shows your wrapper class, it doesn’t show how you’re driving it, which is where your problem will be.

Comment: I just came across your other post on a very similar if not identical issue.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49912975/sending-bulk-emails-through-phpmailer

My fault for not reading the correct samples. Thank you very much.

Comment: If you have 100 recipients in your list and you don’t call clearAddresses, you will be sending 1+2+3...+100 messages, not just 100, which may be why it seems slow.